# Image left their layer while move them in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.7

## Problem

I'm learning PyGame from today. I'm Trying to move images with keys. I've Coded everything. But When I try to move the image, it left his layer on the window. the keys are a,d,s,w. [here is a screenshot of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICqiP.png).

## Code

Here is the Code:

```
import pygame as pg

app=pg.init()
win=pg.display
display=win.set_mode((900,500))
display.fill((255,255,255))
win.set_caption('Python Game')
clock=pg.time.Clock()
vel=5
spship_red=pg.image.load('assets/spaceship_red.png')
spship_red=pg.transform.rotate(pg.transform.scale(spship_red,(55,40)),90)
spship_yellow=pg.image.load('assets/spaceship_yellow.png')
spship_yellow=pg.transform.rotate(pg.transform.scale(spship_yellow,(55,40)),270)
sp=pg.image.load('assets/space.png')
#gun=pg.music.load('assets/Gun+Silencer.mp3')
#nade=pg.music.load('assets/Grenade+1.mp3')


def move(key,red,yellow):
    if key[pg.K_a]:
        red.x-=vel
    if key[pg.K_d]:
        red.x+=vel
    if key[pg.K_w]:
        red.y-=vel
    if key[pg.K_s]:
        red.y+=vel

def draw(red,yellow):
    display.blit(spship_red,(red.x,red.y))
    display.blit(spship_yellow,(yellow.x,yellow.y))


def main():
    red=pg.Rect(100,220,40,55)
    yellow=pg.Rect(760,220,40,55)
    run=True
    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type==pg.QUIT:
                run=False
        key=pg.key.get_pressed()
        move(key,red,yellow)
        draw(red,yellow)
        win.update()

    pg.quit()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to clear the display in ever frame:

```py
def main():
    red=pg.Rect(100,220,40,55)
    yellow=pg.Rect(760,220,40,55)
    run=True
    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type==pg.QUIT:
                run=False
        key=pg.key.get_pressed()
        move(key,red,yellow)

        display.fill((255,255,255))  # <---

        draw(red,yellow)
        win.update()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)